# Impossible to tune Simulink Parameter at simulation time

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink, matlab-compiler

I have a problem. I have an embedded function in my simulink model which has a structure (struct) as parameter. It contains only numerical values and I generate an S-Function of the embedded function by right clicking on the block and C/C++ code --> Generate S-function.

I then have the compiled block, if I try to change some values of my struct nothing changes (the fields of my struct stay the same as when I first compiled my embedded function).

When I compiled the embedded function block I selected the parameter to be tunable. I selected the parameter to be tunable in the Model Explorer. I tried to follow this video tutorial by mathworks: http://fr.mathworks.com/videos/tunable-structure-parameters-68947.html (The video is for r2010a while I am at r2015b) It is a bit different the interface in r2015b (from the one in the video) but when I click on Configure , like the guy does in the video, nothing happens.

Could you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had also decided to reduce the number of tunable parameters by checking the 'inline parameters' checkbox and then specifying the exception variables (variable that have the permission to be tunable even when 'inline parameters' is turned on. It did not work.

In case you aim does not heavily rely on optimization, it would be better if you simply turn off 'inline parameters'.

After that, the constant blocks (i suppose you are giving the input to your s-function from constant blocks) will become tunable.

Another advice: add mex  in the init function of your model callbacks. It will save you from getting weird output (usually due to uncleared/un-reset variables from previous runs).

Hope it helps!